# pausar o reproducir la cancion que este sonando desde otro boton con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo un reproductor con 3 canciones. cada canción tiene su icono de "play" y en otro div "reproductorcontroles" tengo un icono de "play" desde donde quiero pausar o reproducir la canción que este sonando.

Este div "reproductorcontroles" esta oculto y al reproducir una canción se muestra. por eso ya hay una canción sonando y puedo pararla pero quiero que al pulsar otra vez en el icono se vuelva a reproducir. pero como le indico a este div que canción se estaba reproduciendo para que ejecute el .play(), es decir como puedo saber el data-audio que se estaba reproduciendo????

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
        if(audios[i] != e.target){
            audios[i].pause();
        }
    }
}, true);



 $(document).on('click', '.play', function()
 {
  
  var whichAudio = $('#audio' + $(this).data('audio'));
  document.getElementById("reproductorcontroles").style.height = "45px";
  whichAudio[0].paused
  ? whichAudio[0].play() 
  : whichAudio[0].pause();  



 });



//aqui ejecuto pausar desde el div reproductorcontroles

$(document).on('click', '.playlista', function(e)
{
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
     for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++)
     {
        if(audios[i] != e.target)
        {
         audios[i].pause();
         
        }

   
           
    }
});
```

```css
#reproductorcontroles
{
 width: 100%;
 margin:  0 auto;
 height: 0px;
 background-color: #658955 ;
 position: fixed;
 transition: height .4s;
 bottom: 0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="play" data-audio="1">cancion 1</li>

  <li  class="play" data-audio="2">cancion 2</li>
 
  <li  class="play" data-audio="3">cancion 3</li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio1">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio2">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio3">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3">
</audio>
  
             <div id="reproductorcontroles">
                      
                                   
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="playlista"> play/pause
                                        
                                        </li>
                                     </ul>
                               </div>
                              
                           
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no se entiende bien lo que quieres... En cuando suene la canción 1 quieres que se muestre en `playlista` la canción 1?

Comment: No. en playlista lo que quiero es pausar / reproducir la cancion que este sonando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los comentarios te he puesto los cambios:

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
        if(audios[i] != e.target){
            audios[i].pause();
        }
    }
}, true);

// Pon la variable whichAudio "global"
var whichAudio;

$(document).on('click', '.play', function() {
  
 whichAudio = $('#audio' + $(this).data('audio'));
 document.getElementById("reproductorcontroles").style.height = "45px";
 whichAudio[0].paused
 ? whichAudio[0].play() 
 : whichAudio[0].pause();
});


// Aqui simplemente pausa/reproduce la cancion elegida
$(document).on('click', '.playlista', function(e) {
 whichAudio[0].paused
 ? whichAudio[0].play() 
 : whichAudio[0].pause();
});
```

```css
#reproductorcontroles
{
 width: 100%;
 margin:  0 auto;
 height: 0px;
 background-color: #658955 ;
 position: fixed;
 transition: height .4s;
 bottom: 0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="play" data-audio="1">cancion 1</li>
  <li  class="play" data-audio="2">cancion 2</li> 
  <li  class="play" data-audio="3">cancion 3</li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio1">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio2">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio3">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3">
</audio>
  
<div id="reproductorcontroles">
  <ul>
    <li class="playlista"> play/pause</li>
  </ul>
</div>                              
                           
</body>
</html>
```